# Shortened Ids: How to Configure Big Integer IDs with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I am working with a RESTful API, which serves back data to my ember app in **big integer** format.  For example:

```
{
    "users":[
        {
            "id":25969533824547743811785852951
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

However, Handlebars will display `id`s in a sort of scientific notation:

> 2.5969533824547745e+28

So that the `link-to` route is broken, and the url `user/2.5969533824547745e+28/edit` will not resolve.

How can I map **big integer** `id`s in Ember, so that the IDs are not represented in short-hand or scientific notation?

Comment: Posted issue on GitHub: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2179

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to just send a string. Ember-Data internally uses strings for IDs anyways, so thats the easiest way. The RestAdapter just uses the JSON object passed in from $.Ajax https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L741 
In theory we could implement a custom JSON parser that would first cast ids as string before processing the string but that seems like an overkill and slow. If you cannot change the API that is the method I would look at. Probably just use the returnText from jquery, find/replace all ids as strings and then parseJSON.

[node.js is there any proper way to parse JSON with large numbers? (long, bigint, int64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755125/node-js-is-there-any-proper-way-to-parse-json-with-large-numbers-long-bigint) might be helpful