# Number value changes on JSON.parse( )

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, vine

I'm using Node/Express to make API requests to [the unofficial Vine API](https://github.com/starlock/vino/wiki/API-Reference).

The data that the `GET https://api.vineapp.com/users/search/` route returns changes on parsing.

My code is the following:

```
request({ url: 'https://api.vineapp.com/users/search/' + username }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(typeof body,'UNPARSED BODY:', body);

  body = JSON.parse(body);

  console.log(typeof body,'PARSED BODY:', JSON.stringify(body, null, 2));

  cb(null, body)
});
```

This is what is returns:
[image]
**The data.records.userId changes on parsing.**

Why does this happen? Am I missing something here? Why would they do that?

Comment: What is the userId before you parse the response? Also are you using any custom validations or custom types (like mongodb's ObjectId field type) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number is too high for the JSON parser

Info about the highest possible value in javascript:
[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

There is a solution provided here:
[node.js is there any proper way to parse JSON with large numbers? (long, bigint, int64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755125/node-js-is-there-any-proper-way-to-parse-json-with-large-numbers-long-bigint)