# JSON.parse big numbers result in incorrect numbers

Tags: json, node.js

Allright, while parsing a **json object**, the **data** of a key (length of 17 characters) is being modified. I assume it is rounding it which is an issue to me.

```
{
  "Content": "message",
  "User": 21576321584956327
}
```

I'm applying **JSON.parse** on it and the result is:

```
{
  Content: 'message',
  User: 21576321584956320
}
```

**7** has become **0**. I tried stringify on it but the result is: **undefined**

Comment: Don't store large sequences of digits as numbers, store them as strings.

Comment: I tried to! But I do not control that. I cannot edit the fact that the numbers aren't coming as a string.

Comment: Then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755125/node-js-is-there-any-proper-way-to-parse-json-with-large-numbers-long-bigint