# Json max int number

Tags: javascript, json

Tell me please, how do I get the number out of the json, why do zeros appear at the end of the number?

```
var a = '{ "n": 870744036720833075 }';
var json = JSON.parse(a);

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = json.n; // 870744036720833000 why?
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You might need to express this number as either a string or a condensed notation, because it exceeds the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant (9007199254740991)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This integer exceeds what Javascript considers a safe integer. You can test this by running `Number.isSafeInteger(870744036720833075)`, which will return `false`.
Because of this, the number is stored to the maximum available precision.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) for an explanation of max safe integers. A sideeffect of this can be noticed in the documentation.

> Safe in this context refers to the ability to represent integers
>   exactly and to correctly compare them. For example,
>   Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1 === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2 will
>   evaluate to true, which is mathematically incorrect. See
>   Number.isSafeInteger() for more information.

This means that from Javascript's point of view, the number you are creating, and the number it gives you would compare to the same thing.

**UPDATE**

To store the number, you will have to treat it as a string.  Change your json to be `var a = '{ "n": "870744036720833075" }';`

If you need to perform mathematical operations on them, you can find some Javascript libraries that perform mathematical operations on string encoded numbers, such as [strint](https://github.com/rauschma/strint), or the ones suggested in comments.

**UPDATE**

If you are getting this from an external api, you will have to parse the JSON yourself. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18755261/1193647) answer might be a good start for you.

Comment: Thank you, I understand, but how can I get it in the number of div?

Comment: I added an update, but basically, you will have to treat it as a string.