# Should you use JSON string to represent a small Integer?

Tags: json

I understand we should use JSON string to represent large integer and decimal.

If I want to represent integer range from 1 to 1000, is it safe to use JSON Integer and reliable across different platforms?

Comment: Have a look at this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47188576/5686835)**

Comment: *"we should use JSON string to represent large integer and decimal."* -- extracted from its context, this advice is bad practice. Why would you use a string to represent a number? If it is too large and cannot be accurately represented as a number by the language then you won't be able to use it in computations, no matter how you represent it.

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (usually an object or an array). Its purpose is to safely represent the data for storage or transport across the network. It works as a black box: one encodes some data structure as JSON then decodes it back to a data structure similar to that used to create the JSON. The decoding can happen in a different program, written using a different language, running on a different computer. Apart from storing and transferring (and decoding, of course), a JSON is not meant to be used for computations.

Comment: To answer your question: there is no reason to use a string (encoded as JSON or by any other mean) instead of a number, especially when the number can be safely represented as a number in any language and on any hardware platform in use nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I think, yes, its safe to assume that it will be reliable across different platforms.

Refer [JSON.ORG](http://json.org/) standard and one of [similar/duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502398/json-integers-limit-on-size).

Answer (score 0):

> I understand we should use JSON string to represent large integer and decimal.

The [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), one of the documents that define the JSON format, says nothing about it. If the value is a *number*, represent it as a [*number*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-6).

However such document allows implementations to set limits on the range and precision of numbers accepted.

> If I want to represent integer range from 1 to 1000, is it safe to use JSON Integer and reliable across different platforms?

Of course.