# Issue while displaying a number of 18 digit size in java script

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object which contains id and price.

Suppose the maximum length "price" field can hold is of 18 digits.

Now I want to print the id and price but whenever I am printing the price, I'm not getting the actual price value.

Later I came to know that Numbers in JavaScript have limited precision having max size 2**53-1.

I also tried using BigInt because of big size of price field but no luck. like :- 
`alert(BigInt(data.programs[0].price));`

How can I display the price field value correctly?

```json
$(document).ready(function() {             
  var data = { "programs": [ { "id":100, "price":123456789123456789 }, { "id":200, "price":123456789987654321 } ] };
  $.each(data.programs, function (i) {
    $.each(data.programs[i], function (key, val) {
      alert(key +" : "+ val);
    });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: You can use `BigInt`, but only if the JSON object can pass the value of `price` as a _string_. As long as it's a number, you're out of luck.

Comment: You can't parse a JSON with a big number directly, you'll need to extract the string manually somehow. You might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755125/node-js-is-there-any-proper-way-to-parse-json-with-large-numbers-long-bigint)

Comment: @robertklep :- This issue is bcoz the price field is number. If it would have been a string, I wouldn't have posted this question.

Comment: If you can't control the JSON, you have to resort to the method suggested in the answer for the question that @G-man links to.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502398/json-integers-limit-on-size