# How to properly parse a JSON string containing very large numbers?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm struggling with parsing a JSON string containing really large numbers.

Consider the following JSON string:

```
const jsonString = `{
    "id": "eb2552e1673f4ad6bb70923e5920bbab",
    "Int32": 2147483647,
    "Int64": 9223372036854775807,
    "Int64Array": [9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775806],
    "Object": {
        "Int321": 2147483647,
        "Int641": 9223372036854775807,
        "Int64Array1": [9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775806]
    }
}`;
```

My objective is to create a JSON object out of this string.

With `JSON.parse(jsonString)`, I get the following result:

```
{ 
    id: 'eb2552e1673f4ad6bb70923e5920bbab',
    Int32: 2147483647,
    Int64: 9223372036854776000,
    Int64Array: [ 9223372036854776000, 9223372036854776000 ],
    Object:
    { 
        Int321: 2147483647,
        Int641: 9223372036854776000,
        Int64Array1: [ 9223372036854776000, 9223372036854776000 ] 
    } 
}
```

As you can see from above `9223372036854775807` and `9223372036854775806` change to `9223372036854776000` and that is really not acceptable.

Then I read about [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) and using the `reviver` parameter in [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and changed my code to something like:

```
const parsedJSON2 = JSON.parse(jsonString, (key, value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'number') {
    return BigInt(value).toString();
  } else {
    return value;
  }
});
```

And this time the output is:

```
{ 
    id: 'eb2552e1673f4ad6bb70923e5920bbab',
    Int32: '2147483647',
    Int64: '9223372036854775808',
    Int64Array: [ '9223372036854775808', '9223372036854775808' ],
    Object:
    { 
        Int321: '2147483647',
        Int641: '9223372036854775808',
        Int64Array1: [ '9223372036854775808', '9223372036854775808' ] 
    } 
}
```

This is somewhat better than the previous one, however here `9223372036854775807` and `9223372036854775806` change to `9223372036854775808` so it is still not accurate.

I am wondering if there's a better way to parse JSON containing really large numbers. I am completely fine converting these numbers into strings as long as I can have 100% fidelity in conversion.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need send a string from server side. By the time `typeof value === 'number'` runs, it would be parsed to number and lost it's precision

Comment: @adiga...Thank you for your comment. Much appreciated. Unfortunately the server is not in my control :(. I am consuming an API in my application and this is the response I am getting from the API.

Comment: You'd have to use a library ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18755261/3082296)) OR use some regex to add quotes around big numbers before parsing.

Comment: Because Javascript treat all numbers as `double`. The MAX_Value without losing precision is `9007199254740991`.the only way is to make double parse by iterating the object and convert numbers to strings then parse them to JSON.

Comment: @adiga....using `json-bigint` package solved it! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. Would you mind closing this question as duplicate of the one you linked in your comment? Thanks!!!