# Why does to_jsonb() convert bigint to number in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am using KnexJS to fetch data from PostgreSQL and in some places, I use the following pattern:-

```
select to_jsonb(s.*) as student, to_jsonb(st.*) as subject_test
from subject_tests st
inner join students s on st.student_id = s.id
where st.date >= '...'
```

The problem I am facing is that if the `id` column in `subject_test` table is a bigint, I get it back as a number in the `subject_test` object. This can be inaccurate since bigint is able to store beyond the range of javascript number type. Why does `to_jsonb` not convert bigint to string in json instead? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Because JSON can represent arbitrarily large numbers. Only JavaScript's number type cannot, and `JSON.parse` doesn't care. See the [various](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues/162) [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18755125/1048572) about how to parse JSON to native js `BigInt`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use casting operator `::` to convert to bigint to text

Example:

```
create table test(id bigint, name varchar);
insert into test values(1,'A');
insert into test values(2,'B');


select to_jsonb(t1) from test t1

to_jsonb
----------------------
{"id": 1, "name": "A"}
{"id": 2, "name": "B"}



select to_jsonb(t1.*) from (
select id::text,name from test) t1


to_jsonb
{"id": "1", "name": "A"}
{"id": "2", "name": "B"}
```