# How to make JSON.parse() to treat all the Numbers as BigInt?

Tags: javascript, json

I have some numbers in json which overflow the Number type, so I want it to be bigint, but how?

```js
{"foo":[[0],[64],[89],[97]],"bar":[[2323866757078990912,144636906343245838,441695983932742154,163402272522524744],[2477006750808014916,78818525534420994],[18577623609266200],[9008333127155712]]}
```

Comment: Probably there's answer available here: [node.js - Is there any proper way to parse JSON with large numbers? (long, bigint, int64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755125/node-js-is-there-any-proper-way-to-parse-json-with-large-numbers-long-bigin)

Comment: SAD. I'd like to get some build-in solution...

Comment: I suggest to use strings and then convert them into `BigInt` numbers. Like some REST APIs doing (like Discord API with BigInt IDs). It's much easier and you event can convert such variables to `BigInt` using built-in converter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### TLDR;

You may employ `JSON.parse()` [*reviver*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) parameter

### Detailed Solution

To control `JSON.parse()` behavior that way, you can make use of the second parameter of `JSON.parse` ([`reviver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter)) - the function that pre-processes key-value pairs (and may potentially pass desired values to [`BigInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)).

Yet, the values recognized as numbers will still be *coerced* (the credit for pinpointing this issue goes to @YohanesGultom).

To get around this, you may enquote your *big numbers* (to turn them into strings) in your source JSON string, so that their values are preserved upon converting to `bigint`.

As long as you wish to convert to `bigint` only certain numbers, you would need to pick up appropriate criteria (e.g. to check whether the value exceeds `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` with [`Number.isSafeInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger), as @PeterSeliger has suggested).

Thus, your problem may be solved with something, like this:

```js
// source JSON string

const input = `{"foo":[[0],[64],[89],[97]],"bar":[[2323866757078990912,144636906343245838,441695983932742154,163402272522524744],[2477006750808014916,78818525534420994],[18577623609266200],[9008333127155712]]}`


// function that implements desired criteria
// to separate *big numbers* from *small* ones
//
// (works for input parameter num of type number/string)

const isBigNumber = num => !Number.isSafeInteger(+num)


// function that enquotes *big numbers* matching
// desired criteria into double quotes inside
// JSON string
//
// (function checking for *big numbers* may be
// passed as a second parameter for flexibility)

const enquoteBigNumber = (jsonString, bigNumChecker) =>
    jsonString
        .replaceAll(
            /([:\s\[,]*)(\d+)([\s,\]]*)/g,
            (matchingSubstr, prefix, bigNum, suffix) =>
                bigNumChecker(bigNum)
                    ? `${prefix}"${bigNum}"${suffix}`
                    : matchingSubstr
        )


// parser that turns matching *big numbers* in
// source JSON string to bigint

const parseWithBigInt = (jsonString, bigNumChecker) =>
    JSON.parse(
        enquoteBigNumber(jsonString, bigNumChecker),
        (key, value) =>
            !isNaN(value) && bigNumChecker(value)
                ? BigInt(value)
                : value
    )

// resulting output

const output = parseWithBigInt(input, isBigNumber)


console.log("output.foo[1][0]: \n", output.foo[1][0], `(type: ${typeof output.foo[1][0]})`)
console.log("output.bar[0][0]: \n", output.bar[0][0].toString(), `(type: ${typeof output.bar[0][0]})`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100% !important;}
```

> ***Note:*** you may find RegExp pattern to match strings of digits among JSON values not quite robust, so feel free to come up with yours (as mine was the quickest I managed to pick off the top of my head for demo purposes)

> ***Note:*** you may still opt in for some library, as it was suggested by @YohanesGultom, yet adding [10k](https://bundlephobia.com/package/json-bigint@1.0.0) to your client bundle or [37k](https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/json-bigint) to your server-side dependencies (possibly, to docker image size) for that sole purpose may not be quite reasonable.

Comment: A test could be based too on ... [`Number.isSafeInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger)

Comment: Please be aware that this **doesn't preserve** the number value. If you add one more line `console.log(output.bar[0][0].toString())` you will see `2323866757078990848`. Consider custom parsing or library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bigint

Comment: Another limitation of this solution is that string JSON values that contain only digits are also going to be converted to BigInt, whereas they were probably intended to remain as strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can try my library that solves this problem: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-with-bigint

Example:

```
import { JSONParse } from 'json-with-bigint';
    
const yourJSON = `{"someValue":42,"someBigValue":10000000000000000365}`;

JSONParse(yourJSON); // { someValue: 42, someBigValue: 10000000000000000365n }
```

Library will **automatically figure out what values are `BigInt`**, so no need to pass a list of specific keys with `BigInt` values.

It also supports **consistent round-trip operations** (parse - stringify - parse). Deserialized values will be the same as the ones you serialized initially and vice versa.

```
import { JSONParse, JSONStringify } from 'json-with-bigint';
    
const yourJSON = `{"someValue":42,"someBigValue":10000000000000000365}`;

JSONParse(yourJSON); // { someValue: 42, someBigValue: 10000000000000000365n }
JSONStringify(data); // '{"someValue":42,"someBigValue":10000000000000000365}'
JSONParse(JSONStringify(data)); // { someValue: 42, someBigValue: 10000000000000000365n }
```

Comment: Sorry, `{ "foo": 123n }` is not a valid JSON. You are defining a new language.

Comment: **Fixed in version 2.0.0**

It's an internal format used to identify values that should be parsed as BigInt. 

Without it a value like `26n` would be converted to `26`. Which is fine when you want to send JSON to back end, but can lead to type errors if you use JSON as a localStorage value in front end.

But you're right, since this library is called `JSON-with-bigint`, it should generate valid JSON.
I made changes to the code. Now it will always generate a valid JSON. 
Compatibility with strings generated by `JSONStringify()` in previous versions of the lib is also preserved.